why gtsummary() hide some rows of the categorical variable
I want to generate table using gtsummary() package but it hides the categories for some factor variables.
I use the following code
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)

# Example data setup (simulated based on your example)
data <- data.frame(
  A = factor(c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes")),
  B = factor(c("Men", "Women", "Women", "Men", "Women")),
  C = factor(c("Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes")))

# Convert factors to proper factors if needed
data$A <- factor(data$A, levels = c("No", "Yes"))
data$B <- factor(data$B, levels = c("Men", "Women"))
data$C <- factor(data$C, levels = c("No", "Yes"))

# Summary table with gtsummary
tbl <- data %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = C)
tbl

I get
Characteristic  No, N = 2  Yes, N = 3
A               1 (33%)    2 (67%)
B
  Women         2 (67%)    1 (33%)
1 n (%)

The cross tab gives the correct result like bellow
> table(data$A, data$C)
     
      No Yes
  No   2   0
  Yes  1   2

But I can't generate this cross tab in tbl_summary()

This is explained in the function's help file: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_summary.html#type-argument-1
